# Handling broadcast message (creating, getting id) for messenger bot

Tags: javascript, facebook-messenger-bot

I am newbie and I use starter project from glitch. 
Here is link to my project:
https://glitch.com/edit/#!/lucky-spandex

Can you explain me how to get message_broadcast_id and how to create that?

Normal message I create by:

```
function callSendAPI(messageData) {
  request({
    uri: 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messages',
    qs: { access_token: process.env.PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN },
    method: 'POST',
    json: messageData

  }, function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
      var recipientId = body.recipient_id;
      var messageId = body.message_id;

      console.log("Successfully sent generic message with id %s to recipient %s", 
        messageId, recipientId);
    } else {
      console.error("Unable to send message.");
      console.error(response);
      console.error(error);
    }
  });  
}
```

And processing messages:

```
// Message processing
app.post('/webhook', function (req, res) {
  console.log(req.body);
  var data = req.body;

  // Make sure this is a page subscription
  if (data.object === 'page') {

    // Iterate over each entry - there may be multiple if batched
    data.entry.forEach(function(entry) {
      var pageID = entry.id;
      var timeOfEvent = entry.time;

      // Iterate over each messaging event
      entry.messaging.forEach(function(event) {
        if (event.message) {
          receivedMessage(event);
        } else if (event.postback) {
          receivedPostback(event);   
        }else {
          console.log("Webhook received unknown event: ", event);
        }
      });
    });

    // Assume all went well.
    //
    // You must send back a 200, within 20 seconds, to let us know
    // you've successfully received the callback. Otherwise, the request
    // will time out and we will keep trying to resend.
    res.sendStatus(200);
  }
});
```

Should I get message id in object event.message_broadcast_id?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the message before you can broadcast it.

Check out the function "creativeBroadcastMessage"

Comment: I can not create broadcast message. I have got error:
https://pastebin.com/D6GxQeTn

Comment: I see the following in your logs. What is the request you are sending?

  statusCode: 400, 
  statusMessage: 'Bad Request',

Comment: I made typo in message data. Instead of messages I wrote message without 's'.

Answer (score 0):

I made typo in message data. Instead of messages I wrote message without 's'